# Alterar entre janelas - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde.

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para alterar entre janelas durante um processo. Criei um código com selenium para acessar um site, acessar uma área logada e depois clicar em opções para anexar o arquivo.

É necessário clicar nesses "três pontinhos"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e após isso abre a janela do windows para selecionar o arquivo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dificuldade é acessar essa janela e realizar o "alt tab" entre a janela do navegador e do windows. Já tentei utilizando o send_keys, o Keys e o actionChains mas mesmo assim não consegui.

Obrigado.

Comment: Use pyautogui.click, pyautogui.moveTo, e pyautogui.move e seja feliz

Answer (score -1):

Para o envio de arquivos você não precisa realizar o click, você pode apenar usar dessa forma, passando o localizador e o caminho do arquivo:

> Imagepath = "C:\User\Desktop\image.png"
> driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/input').send_keys(Imagepath)

Se quiser fazer o click e abrir essa janela de envio, você vai ter de usar o pyautogui.

Comment: Mas o problema é que o arquivo que eu vou usar tem um nome variavel, pois varia de acordo com a data e o horario que serão salvos. Eu defini uma variavel para o caminho (a) e uma variavel para o nome(b) e uma terceira variavel (a+b), se eu inserir o caminho como variavel deve funcionar?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).